# Шаблонный класс с разными шаблонными аргументами в одном массиве

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++

По скольку для объявления массива мы должны указать тип его элементов, то получается если класс шаблонный и мы создаем массив элементов этого класса то они все будут иметь одни и те же аргументы шаблона. Как в массив засунуть элементы одного шаблонного класса, но с разными аргументами шаблона (если возможно)?
К примеру: в `arr[0]` лежит `vector<int>`, а в `arr[1]` уже распологается `vector<char>`.

Comment: Можно использовать [std::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any). `std::vector<std::any> arr;`

Comment: Массив является гомогенным контейнером, то бишь все его элементы по определению имеют один и тот же тип и не могут быть разными специализациями шаблона.

Comment: Если вам такое нужно, то в архитектуре вашего приложения что-то явно пошло не так.

Comment: Просто поставил перед собой челендж реализовать в с++ возможность обращения полям класса как в js через `[]` например `obj["name"]`. И да я знаю про `map` да и не выйдет с помощью `map` создать кучу одинаковых объектов

Comment: В вашем "челлендже" слишком много навалено в одну кучу. Массив с элементами разных типов - это одно. Униформный доступ к членм элементов в таком массиве - другое. А указание имени члена run-time строкой - это третье. Если ваш вопрос обо всем об этом сразу - то это нужно указывать в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Нет никакой принципиальной разницы между массивом `vector<int>` и `vector<char>` и массивом элементов вообще никак друг с другом не связанных типов, вроде `double` и `std::string`. В С++ не бывает массивов с элементами разных типов, поэтому создать такой "массив" можно только умозрительно путем насильного сведения типов элементов к одному общему типу.

Если набор интересующих вас типов конечен, то это могут быть элементы типа `union`, покрывающего все необходимые вам варианты типов данных. Стандартная библиотека языка С++ предоставляет вам существенно более продвинутый и безопасный вариант этого решения в виде класса `std::variant`.

В универсальном случае это может быть массив указателей `void *`, указывающих на ваши объекты. Стандартная библиотека языка С++ предоставляет вам существенно более продвинутый и безопасный вариант этого решения в виде класса `std::any`.

Answer (score 0):

Я не стану комментировать написанное Вами в вопросе - это уже сделали в комментариях, а сразу перейду к Вашей практической задаче:

> Просто поставил перед собой челендж реализовать в с++ возможность обращения полям класса как в js через [] например obj["name"]

Я предложу Вам простую, неоптимальную, и, возможно, содержащую баги, реализацию, а Вы уже дуймате, использовать ее или нет:

Базовый класс обертки для значений:

```
class holder_base
{
public:
    using ptr = std::shared_ptr<holder_base>;

public:
    virtual ~holder_base() = default;
};
```

Обертка для объекта конкретного типа:

```
template<typename T>
class value_holder : public holder_base
{
public:
    value_holder() = default;
    explicit value_holder(T value) : m_value(std::move(value)) {}

public:
    auto ref() -> T& { return m_value; }

protected:
    T m_value;
};
```

Контейнер для обертки:

```
class holder_wrapper
{
public:
    explicit holder_wrapper()
        : m_holder()
    {}

public:
    template<typename T>
    auto operator=(T value) -> holder_wrapper&
    {
        m_holder.reset(new value_holder<T>(std::move(value)));
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T>
    auto as() -> T&
    {
        if (!m_holder) m_holder.reset(new value_holder<T>(T()));
        return std::static_pointer_cast<value_holder<T>>(m_holder)->ref();
    }

protected:
    holder_base::ptr m_holder;
};
```

Контейнер:

```
class container
{
public:
    using holder_map_t = std::unordered_map<std::string, holder_wrapper>;

public:
    container() = default;

public:
    auto operator[](const std::string& name) -> holder_wrapper&
    {
        if (m_holders.contains(name))
        {
            return m_holders.at(name);
        }

        auto [it, _] = m_holders.insert(std::make_pair(name, holder_wrapper()));
        return it->second;
    }

protected:
    holder_map_t m_holders;
};
```

Пример:

```
auto main() -> int
{
    container c;
    c["username"] = std::string("Jack");
    c["score"] = 100;

    c["username"].as<std::string>();

    std::cout << c["username"].as<std::string>() << " scored " << c["score"].as<int>() << " points" << std::endl;
}
```