# Можно ли в С++ как нибудь создать массив который будет хранить несколько типов переменных?

Tags: c++

Можно ли в С++ как нибудь создать массив который будет хранить несколько типов переменных?

Comment: можно, но лучше так не делать

Comment: `union` или [`variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) вас не устроят?..

Comment: туда можно же динамично добавлять елементы?

Comment: `union` и `std::variant` - это не замена массиву; это то, что должно быть элементом массива. Можно добавлять элементы или нет - зависит от того, в чем их хранить. В какой-нибудь `std::vector<std::variant<int, float>>` можно, а в `std::variant<int, float> array[10];` - нельзя.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1049440/182825

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя, но для хранения разнотипных значений можно использовать `std::tuple`, `std::vector<std::variant>`, `std::vector<UnionType>`